# Is it correct to say that mass is just amount of energy in object?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, mass-energy, higgs

Is it correct to say that mass is just amount of energy in object? Why do we say that the mass of the electron is given by the Higgs mechanism, while the mass of a nucleus is the result of the energy associated to the strong force?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of mass as the amount of energy that an object has when it is at rest. If we take the energy-momentum equation:
$$E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$$
we can see that for $p=0$:
$$E=mc^2$$

The mass of elementary particles (such as leptons, quarks, $W$ and $Z$ bosons) is a consequence of their interaction with the Higgs field. We say that they couple with the Higgs field. Protons and neutrons are made of quarks and gluons. A small part of the mass of the protons and the neutrons is given by the sum of the masses of the quarks and mostly by the interaction between the quarks through the gluon fields.
Protons and neutrons form a bound state in the atomic nucleus. They interact via strong nuclear interaction. The mass of nucleus is given by the difference between the mass of the nucleons (protons and neutrons) and the nuclear binding energy (due to the interaction between nucleons).